# Polyamory Network problem

Tags: graph-theory, network, graph-connectivity

Two Related Problems:

1.
Imagine polyamorous people form a complicated network.
Define each person as a unique node. 
Define a relationship between two people as an edge.

Each node can possibly have N types of edges to directly connect to another node. 
Each node at least needs to connect one of the rest of the nodes with one of the N types of edges, so that each node connected with each node, directly or through other nodes.
Imagine there are X nodes, how many possible variations of the network are there?

2. Imagine the nodes are now indistinguishable from each other. How many possible variations of the network are there?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Problem 1 seems to be about counting simple graphs on N vertices.  If the counting is for *labelled* graphs, an answer lies in counting the possible subsets of edges.  But if the counting is for *unlabelled* graphs,  the counting is more difficult because one counts only isomorphism classes of simple graphs. Please clarify.

Comment: Hi Hardmath! Thank you for your kind clarification. It is the second problem counting unlabeled graphs, which you gave the question name "isomorphism classes of simple graphs", I really need to solve. I solved the first one myself. It is for my dissertation on polyamory. I want to give a systematic account of all morphisms of a network that has N nodes and X types of edges between each node. If you could help me the least I can do is to put you on the credit list when my dissertation is defended. Thank you!

Comment: If I didn't use the terms wrong, it should be graph with vertexes unlabeled but edges labeled.